# How can I detect an IFrame changing src using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe which I'm loading dynamically based on a parameter in the URL coming in. There are also certain actions on the page a user can take that change the src of the iframe to display another page. Is there a JavaScript function which I can bind to that will tell me when the src changes?

For instance the user browses to my page and I dynamically load "www.mysite.com/page1"
Now the user does something and page1 is replaced by "www.mysite.com/page2".

I'd like to detect the change and act on it. Something like: document.getElementById("myIFrame").onSrcChange(doFunction());

And before anyone asks, no I can't detect the user does something part, I have to rely on the iFrame change as what to try and detect.

If it makes any difference, this must work in IE. Thanks!

Comment: do you need to detect that change before iframe new URL is loaded or if event is triggered later that will help you? you can use onload event after new URL is loaded.

Comment: Or you can try onhashchange to detect URL change

Comment: onload fires when the url changes but it also fires the first time I set the src, even if I create the onload function after the src is set. Very frustrating. The onhashchange method didn't seem to work at all for me. It just never fired.

Comment: Solved my problem - a combination of onload + counting the back button presses got me to where I wanted to be. Please answer the question using "onload" and I'll mark it as the answer, as it does indeed detect the changing of src on an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "onload" event on iframe tag to detect iframe src change, when src is changed new page is loaded in iframe and "onload" event is triggered.

you can also use on "onhashchange" event to detect hash changes as well.